# divide every single value in an array on the next value to return a number

Tags: php, loops, math, foreach

how can i using php divide every single value in an array on the next value to return a number like a have an array

i want a function that divide 1/2/3/4/5 and it should return this value **(0.0083333333333333)**
i have tried this

```
<?php
    function vo(){
     $newArray=array(1,2,3,4,5);
        $resulte=1;
            foreach($newArray as $value){
             $resulte=$value/$resulte;
        }}
vo();
?>
```

output for this code, resulte=1.875

i think im bad at math not sure tho

Comment: Start by adding [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to identify the obvious errors

Comment: Then taking function scope into account, pass the array you are processing into the function so it can actually see it i.e. `vo($newArray);`

Comment: No try and `echo vo()` and returning a result from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$your_array = [1,2,3,4,5];
$result = $your_array[0]; //result defaulted to first element in array;

for($i=1; $i<sizeof($your_array); $i++){ //loop starts from 2nd                                           //element in array
  $result /= $your_array[$i];
}
```

code explanation: set initial value of $result to first element of array, as this is the first thing that you said you want to divide;

start looping through your array from 2nd element, and set the value of $result to it's current value divided by the current element in the loop (this is why /= is used)

the final value of $result, becomes the accumulated result of the division of each element of the array divided by the element next to it.

if you output $result, you will get 0.0083333333333333

Answer (score 1):

You got your division backwards. You want to divide by the next number in the list, therefore your `$resulte = $value / $resulte` should be `$resulte = $resulte / $value`. Also remember to add a `print($resulte)` after the loop.